# "Undefined" message in jqgrid, "b.jgrid.formatter is undefined"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, undefined

when I'm sending JSON response to jqgrid I get "undefined" message across it and Firebug is telling me this:

```
b.jgrid.formatter is undefined

[Break On This Error]   

...input===true){b(".ui-pg-input",l).val(a.p.page);h=a.p.toppager?"#sp_1"+m+",#sp_1...
```

which basically doesn't tell me much.

This happens when I'm sending empty response:

```
{"total":0,"page":1,"records":0,"rows":[]}
```

or response with records. Records are then visible in grid. After this "undefined" message is shown up, I can't browse through pages as, of course, the bug in code appeared.

As @Oleg suggested I'm providing here additional info:

1. These are javascripts I'm using:

   ```
   jquery.validate.min.js
   jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
   jquery-1.5.1.min.js
   jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js
   jquery.jqGrid.min.js
   ui/jquery.ui.core.js
   ui/jquery.ui.widget.js
   ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js
   ```

   My javascript source:

   ```
   var grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
               datatype: 'json',

               caption: 'Transaction Log',
               hiddengrid: 'true',
               postData: {
                   companyId: function () { return $("#SelectedCompany").val(); },
                   userId: function () { return $("#SelectedUser").val(); },
                   dateFromString: function () { return $("#DateFrom").val(); },
                   dateToString: function () { return $("#DateTo").val(); }
               },
               url: '@Url.Action("GetTransactionLogData")',
               mtype: 'GET',
               colNames: ['Ref.', 'TradeDate', 'Status', 'LegalEntity', ...],
               colModel: [
                   { name: 'Reference', index: 'Reference', width: '60' },
                   { name: 'TradeDate', index: 'TradeDate', width: '70' },
                   { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: '50' },
                   { name: 'LegalEntity', index: 'LegalEntity', width: '80' },
                   ...
               ],
               pager: $('#pager'),
               rowNum: 10,
               height: '100%'

           });
   ```

   I've downloaded last version of jqGrid from [this link][1], it's says it's **4.4.0** version.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case of such errors you should always 1) repeat the same with `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` 2) you should specify the exact version of jqGrid which you use 3) you should include the list of JavaScript files which you loaded on the page. The order of loading could be *very important*. 4) you should include the JavaScript code which defines jqGrid.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, thank you for providing me with this list of details that I should present here in order to find solution with the community.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's important to include `grid.locale-en.js` *before* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to make jqGrid working.

Additionally I would recommend you to add `gridview: true` option to jqGrid and replace `pager: $('#pager')` to `pager: '#pager'` because jqGrid need the id selector of the pager only. If you use `pager: $('#pager')` then jqGrid will replace the parameter to `pager: '#pager'`. So the form `pager: $('#pager')` has really no sense as the jqGrid parameter.

Comment: @DevetiPutnik: `$.jgrid.formatter` will be defined in `grid.locale-en.js` and will be extended and used in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. So the text "b.jgrid.formatter is undefined" could be just because you didn't included `grid.locale-en.js`. Did you tried your code with  `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`? Which error you get and in which line of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`?

Comment: Thank you very much! I  rearranged the list a bit and now everything is working great!

Comment: Good catch @Oleg . I added your solution to blog: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/jqgrid-typeerror-b-jgrid-formatter-is-undefined/ Thanks

Comment: There's no JS error now, but I see "Warning
Please, select row". This is when the returned list is empty

Comment: @CsabaToth: Sorry, but I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. In any way the language file `grid.locale-en.js` or other `grid.locale-XX.js` should be included before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`

Comment: @Oleg Yes, that solved the JS error and I marked your answer as correct! The other thing I refer to is a separate issue.